# Set TextView from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a `Activity` which is called SpotDetails, in the `onCreate` i starts a `AsyncTask` in another activity. The `AsyncTask` then downloads and parses an `xml` file and the result should be outputted into a `TextView` in the SpotDetails `Activity`.

How do i accomplish this ?
Snippet from main class (SpotDetails) :

```
public TextView TextView_WindStrenghFromVindsiden, spoTextView;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spot_overview);
    //Recive intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //Set strings to information from the intent

    //Create a intance of Place with information
    place = vindsiden.createSted(intent.getStringExtra("StedsNavn"));
    //   TextView spoTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spot_overview_WindDegreesForeCastFromYRinfo);

    spoTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spot_overview_WindDegreesForeCastFromYRinfo);

    String URL = place.getNB_url();
    DomXMLParser domXMLParser = new DomXMLParser();

    //domXMLParser.DownloadXML(URL);
    domXMLParser.DownloadXML(URL, this);


    //
```

Snippet from `AsyncTask` (DomXMLParser.java) :

```
 TextView tv;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        tv = (TextView) spotDetails.findViewById(R.id.spot_overview_WindDegreesForeCastFromYRinfo);
        // Create a progressbar
```

---

-----Snippet from `onPostExecute`

```
 tv.setText(yrMeasurmentList.get(0).getWindDirection_degree());
```

Exception : 
http://pastebin.com/WEqSdc1t

(StackOwerflow woth recognize my Exception as code. )

Comment: before entering to the doinbackground() set the textview as null

Comment: wont that be the same as setting the textview in the onPreExecute as null ?

Comment: Didnt seem to work either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't** put your `AsyncTask` in another activity. If you have `AsyncTask`s you are using in various places, you can either put them in a utility class or declare them in their own files. If you have an `AsyncTask` which modifies the UI of only one activity, it should be declared in that activity. If the `AsyncTask` is used by multiple activities, then you could pass the `Activity` in the constructor, store it as a private field, and resolve the views in `onPostExecute()`:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask... {
    WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;

    public MyAsyncTask( Activity activity ) {
        super();
        mActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>( activity );
    }

    ...

    public void onPostExecute(...) {
        Activity act = mActivity.get();
        if( act != null ) {
            TextView tv = act.findViewById( ...id... );
            tv.setText( "Hello World" );
        } else {
            // the Activity was destroyed
        }
    }

}
```

Note: I'm using a WeakReference there which will help alleviate most issues with long running AsyncTasks.

Comment: Thanks i followed just as you said in the code and it worked perfectly. As of your comment i already do just as you told :)